# The general meaning of "constraint relaxation" in the context of the Shortest Path Problem

Tags: constraint, algorithms, graphs, dynamic-programming, relaxation

I've read that in the context of the Shortest Path Problem, the use of the term "relaxation" ("relaxing edges")

> [...][the use of the term "relaxation"] is historical. The outcome of a relaxation step can be viewed as a relaxation
>   of the constraint $d[v] \le d[u] + w(u, v)$, [...]

So, I looked for the general meaning of "constraint relaxation" and found some examples, such as [Lagrangian relaxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_relaxation), but i do not see how Lagrangian relaxation would be relevant to relaxing a single constraint $x_j\le x_i + w_{i,j}$.

Lagrangian relaxation and such modify the problem (making the constraints more "relaxed" in the process), but the relaxation used in the Shortest Path algorithms modifies a tentative solution and does not seem to modify the problem...

What is the general meaning of the "relaxation" used in the Shortest Path Problem?

To be clear, I am asking about the relaxation step described, for example, on pages 276-277 of [*Algorithms*](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/) by Jeff Erickson, Chapter 8. Here it is:

```
Relax(u, v):
    d[v] <- d[u] + w(u, v)
    p[v] <- u
```

Links:

- [*Shortest Paths* chapter](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/08-sssp.pdf) from [*Algorithms*](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/)
  by Jeff Erickson.
- [Some blog post where the term is explained.](https://towardsdatascience.com/algorithm-shortest-paths-1d8fa3f50769)
- [Some slides where the term is used.](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-18-shortest-paths-ii-bellman-ford-linear-programming-difference-constraints/lec18.pdf)

Comment: So far I could not find a satisfactory explanation of why "relax" would be an appropriate term for this operation.  I am wondering if the use of this term is not a historical mistake.  I am considering using the expression "enforce arc constraint" instead of "relax arc constraint" for the operation in question.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, the term *relaxation* is used to indicate that a constraint (or a group of constraints) is removed from the model, rendering a model that is more loose, less constrained.

In the context of *Lagrangian relaxation*, a constraint (or group of constraints) is removed from the model, and added to the objective function with a coefficient (or more precisely, the right hand term minus the left hand term). The idea is that if this additional term has value $0$ in the objective function, the constraint is satisfied.

The term *linear relaxation* is also very common. It appears when integrity constraints are removed from the model (variables that have to be discrete can be continuous).

For the shortest path problem, it is the same : one of the constraint that models the shortest path is removed, in some sense. You can model the shortest path problem from $u$ to $v$ in a graph $G=(V,E)$ as follows : 
$$
\max \; d_v
$$
subject to
\begin{align}
d_j &\le d_i + c_{ij} \quad \forall (i,j) \in E \\
d_u &= 0  
\end{align}

In essence, the shortest path from $u$ to $v$, $d_v$, is the largest value that minimizes $d_i+c_{iv}$ for all predecessors $i$ of $v$. The constraint $d_j \le d_i +c_{ij}$ is only active when $d_i$ is the shortest path length to node $i$. When it is not the case, the constraint is inactive and you can relax it from the model. This is what is done dynamically (and not through linear programming) in the slides of the link you have posted.

There is a nice physical interpretation of this. Imagine you have some sort of web with extremities $u$ and $v$. If you stretch $u$ from $v$ as much as possible, the tightest string from $u$ to $v$ is the shortest path from $u$ to $v$. All other strings from $u$ to $v$ are loose or wavy, hence the term "relaxed." This is illustrated in the image below (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)) :

> Finding the shortest path in a graph using optimal substructure; a
>   straight line indicates a single edge; a wavy line indicates a
>   shortest path between the two vertices it connects (among other paths,
>   not shown, sharing the same two vertices); the bold line is the
>   overall shortest path from start to goal.

[image]

For this particular graph, if nodes are named $a$, $b$, $c$ from top to bottom, the above linear formulation yields :

$$
\max \; d_{goal}
$$
subject to
\begin{align}
d_a &\le d_{start}+5 \\
d_b &\le d_{start}+2 \\
d_c &\le d_{start}+11 \\
d_{goal} &\le d_a + 20 \\
d_{goal} &\le d_b + 25 \\
d_{goal} &\le d_c + 17 \\
d_{start} &= 0  \\
\end{align}

Which can easily be simplified to

\begin{align}
d_a &\le 5 \\
d_b &\le 2 \\
d_c &\le 11 \\
d_{goal} &\le d_a + 20 \\
d_{goal} &\le d_b + 25 \\
d_{goal} &\le d_c + 17 
\end{align}

It is easy to see that the last two constraints could be removed from the model : they can be *relaxed*. Physically, if you stretch the graph from $start$ to $goal$, edges $(b,goal)$ and $(c,goal)$ end up wavy/loose/"relaxed".

Comment: I've added a link to some slides where the term is used. I do not see in what sense a constraint is removed. Constraints do not seem to be operated upon explicitly, instead it looks like a search for an "optimal" solution.

Comment: As i said, i do not see the constraint to be removed. Could you explain, please, what constraint satisfaction problem is transformed into what other CSP by removing a constraint when an edge is relaxed? The analogy with springs as shortest paths is quite strange, i do not see what it means...

Comment: Your model of the shortest path problem is not exact: edge weights are not natural numbers, but reals. I suppose that instead of the second family of inequalities, you can use just one: $d_u = 0$. I do not understand the meaning of "the constraint $x_j \le x_i + w_{i,j}$ is only active when $x_i$ is ...". A constraint *a priori* is a condition on variables. For example, i do not know what it mean "$x < y$ is only active if $x = 0$". Could you give me a reference to a general notion of relaxation where constraints on variables can be active or inactive depending on the values of the variables?

Comment: "There is a nice physical interpretation of this. Imagine you have some sort of web with extremities $u$ and $v$. If you stretch $u$ from $v$ as much as possible, the tightest string from $u$ to $v$ is the shortest path from $u$ to $v$." -- this is a strange explanation, since all the edges on the "tightest string" have been relaxed.

Comment: @Alexey : 1/ yes of course variables $d_j$ are continuous, thanks. 2/ In the image, if nodes are called $a$, $b$ $c$ from top to bottom : $d_{goal} = d_{a}+20$ but $d_{goal} < d_{b} + 25$ : the constraint is only active for node $a$. 3/all the edges on the tightest string are not relaxed (none are).

Comment: (2) I do not understand. What is "$d_{\text{goal}} = d_a + 20$"? There is no such constraint. What is wrong with "$d_{\text{start}} = 0$" as a constraint? (3) At what moment? In the end they are all relaxed.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with $d_{start}=0$, I have edited the formulation and added an example to clarify. Hope it helps.

Comment: The constraint formulation of the Shortest Path Problem is again not quite right: there is no constraints $d_j\ge0$. Also, "In essence, the shortest path from $u$ to $v$, $d_v$, is the largest value that minimizes $d_i+c_{iv}$ for all predecessors $i$ of $v$." does not quite make sense.

Comment: This just means that $d_v = \min_{i\mid (i,v) \in A} \{d_i + c_{iv} \}$.

Comment: No, you tentative answer does not help, it does not answer my question (see my previous comments). What you wrote seems to be mostly irrelevant to the relaxation step i am asking about. Moreover, parts of your tentative answer are incorrect or mixed up.

Comment: For example, the picture you posted is from a different algorithm i did not ask about. The relaxation steps there are different. The correct constraint there would be $d_{\text{goal}} = 0$, and it would be $d_{\text{start}}$ to maximize. You are mixing up paths with edges on the picture. Edges that end up "wavy/loose" are not necessarily the same that have been relaxed. On the contrary, the edges on the shortest path have been relaxed. The constraints that you claim can be "removed" are not the same as the edges that will be relaxed. On the contrary, the edge to $a$ will  be relaxed.

Comment: It seems we have a hard time understanding one another. I did my best to answer your question, sorry if it does not help. I will leave it to the community to judge of the quality of the answer. Cheers

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify what relaxation step i am asking about. I hoped that links i provided where enough. If you remove from you answer clearly irrelevant parts (the picture in the end, wavy paths, removing constraints while they are not relaxed by the algorithms, etc.), it might be possible to concentrate on the relaxation I am asking about.

Answer (score 2):

In optimisation theory, creating a relaxation refers to an operation which:

- Creates a superset of an underlying set, if the operation is done on a set
- Produces a new set of functions that define a superset of a set associated with some original function (usually the feasible region).

For instance, if I have a nonconvex function/set, I can create a *convex relaxation* of that function/set:

[image]

Assuming that the set of interest is a feasible region, the usual way to modify the feasible region defined by a constraint is to modify the constraint itself in some way, either by replacing it with a set of different constraints, or by changing that constraint's functional form.

For instance, a convex (and linear) relaxation of $-x^2\leq 0$ is the secant of $-x^2$ between the lower and upper bounds of $x$. Furthermore, said secant (along with the original constraint) defines the *convex hull* of that set, because that's the tightest possible superset we can produce for that feasible region that is still convex.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i was still not clear in my question, but i was asking specifically about the relaxation step in some classical Shortest Path algorithms. What superset of what set is created by the relaxation operation i am asking about?